# Clojure: how is defn different from fn?

Tags: clojure, language-lawyer

If I explicitly define a function like this `(defn f [x] (get x "a"))`,
then both `(-> {"a" 1} f)` and `(f {"a" 1})` work as expected.

However, if I'm using anonymous function, only `(#(get % "a") {"a" 1})` works but `(-> {"a" 1}  #(get % "a"))` throws exception: `CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap cannot \
be cast to clojure.lang.ISeq, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`#(get % "a")` is expanded by the reader:

```
 user=> '#(get % "a")
 (fn* [p1__852#] (get p1__852# "a"))
```

You can ignore the difference between fn and fn* in this case.

`(-> ...)` is a macro that just rethreads its arguments:

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(-> {"a" 1} f))
(f {"a" 1})
```

Note that it only wraps parentheses around f if there aren't ones already, so:

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(-> {"a" 1} (f)))
(f {"a" 1})
```

But that won't work as you might expect when applied to `fn` macros:

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(-> {"a" 1} (fn [x] (get x "a"))))
(fn {"a" 1} [x] (get x "a"))
```

Or on #(...) reader forms:

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(-> {"a" 1} #(get % "a")))
(fn* {"a" 1} [p1__867#] (get p1__867# "a"))
```

The general solution is to put your anonymous function inside a list, though if you can use a named function, I think it reads a lot clearer:

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(-> {"a" 1} (#(get % "a"))))
((fn* [p1__870#] (get p1__870# "a")) {"a" 1})
```